# Leer XML desde un campo de gridview y mostrarlo en un datatable

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net, xml

Visual Studio 2012 - Aplicacion Web.

Deseo recorrer el gridview, al llegar al campo "REQUESTCONTENT" recorrerlo e insertar los valores de ese campo en un datatable.

Este es el gridview:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es el xml en el campo **"REQUESTCONTENT"**:

```
<spRequest>
    <Action>
        <No>1</No>
        <Tx>12345678</Tx>
        <ActionName>Add</ActionName>
        <ActionParameter>
            <Key>ItemId</Key>
            <Value>1</Value>
            </ActionParameter>
        <ActionParameter>
            <Key>Item</Key>
            <Value>Printer</Value>
        </ActionParameter>
        <ActionParameter>
            <Key>Cards</Key>
            <Value>1</Value>
        </ActionParameter>
        <ActionParameter>
            <Key>DateEnd</Key>
            <Value>201812310000</Value>
        </ActionParameter>
        <ActionParameter>
            <Key>DateStart</Key>
            <Value>201801010000</Value>
        </ActionParameter>
    </Action>
</spRequest>
```

Asi deberia ser el resultado en otro gridview:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te dejo una respuesta en Ingles, de lo que necesitas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401280/read-a-xml-from-a-string-and-get-some-fields-problems-reading-xml

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Que intentaste hasta ahora? y cual fue el problema con el cual te enfrentaste?